# FreeRTOS watchdog timeout

Tags: esp32, freertos

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1). 

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x4008c936  PS      : 0x00060735  A0      : 0x8008b8ae  A1      : 0x3ffbf25c  
A2      : 0x3ffba74c  A3      : 0x3ffb97b8  A4      : 0x00000004  A5      : 0x00060723  
A6      : 0x00060723  A7      : 0x00000001  A8      : 0x3ffb97b8  A9      : 0x00000019  
A10     : 0x3ffb97b8  A11     : 0x00000019  A12     : 0x3ffc2f24  A13     : 0x00060723  
A14     : 0x007bf418  A15     : 0x003fffff  SAR     : 0x00000010  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x4008491d  LEND    : 0x40084925  LCOUNT  : 0x00000027  
Core  1 was running in ISR context:
EPC1    : 0x400e2af7  EPC2    : 0x00000000  EPC3    : 0x00000000  EPC4    : 0x00000000


Backtrace: 0x4008c933:0x3ffbf25c |<-CORRUPTED

  #0  0x4008c933:0x3ffbf25c in vListInsert at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/freertos/list.c:183


Core  0 register dump:
PC      : 0x4008cad3  PS      : 0x00060035  A0      : 0x8008b4d7  A1      : 0x3ffbeb3c
A2      : 0x3ffbf418  A3      : 0xb33fffff  A4      : 0x0000abab  A5      : 0x00060023
A6      : 0x00060021  A7      : 0x0000cdcd  A8      : 0x0000abab  A9      : 0xffffffff  
A10     : 0x00000000  A11     : 0x00000000  A12     : 0x3ffc2d34  A13     : 0x00000007
A14     : 0x007bf418  A15     : 0x003fffff  SAR     : 0x0000001a  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x00000000  LEND    : 0x00000000  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000


Backtrace: 0x4008cad0:0x3ffbeb3c |<-CORRUPTED

  #0  0x4008cad0:0x3ffbeb3c in compare_and_set_native at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/esp_hw_support/include/soc/compare_set.h:25
      (inlined by) spinlock_acquire at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/esp_hw_support/include/soc/spinlock.h:103
      (inlined by) xPortEnterCriticalTimeout at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/freertos/port/xtensa/port.c:288




ELF file SHA256: 90689eca1e9c1ace
```

Alguém sabe o que pode estar a acontecer no esp32 para gerar este erro? Se alguém estiver disposto, posso disponibilizar o código.
Já verifiquei e não é nenhum tipo de erro a nível do hardware.

Comment: Hi Albino, this site is in English. Try https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ for Portugese.

Answer (score -1):

I came across this issue a couple of times. Sorry, my Portuguese is not perfect but I'll try to help in English.

This happens when we are trying to allocate **more memory inside a function** than we allowed it initially.

For example:

```
void task1(void *params)
{
  char buffer[3000];
  memset(buffer, 'm', 3000);
}

void app_main()
{

  xTaskCreate(task1, "task1", 2048, NULL, 1, NULL);

}
```

Notice that **xTaskCreate** allows only **2048 bytes**(This differs from vanilla freeRtos which uses **word** as the unit) but we are trying to use **3000 bytes**

I hope this helps, if you can share a portion of the code that works with the memory, I can look more into it.